# How to optimize UICollectionView image loading?

Tags: ios, optimization, uicollectionview

I have number of `.jpg` files in filesystem which need to be displayed in each cell's `UIImageView`. Each image is less than 200Kb. The code for assigning cell image is following:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    BookCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BookCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *coverName = [[_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cover"];
    NSString *cover = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:coverName ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"covers"]; 
    cell.coverImage.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:cover];
    ...    
    return cell;
}
```

The experience is not perfect, particularly on iPad 2. During scroll the view is freezy. I suspect it is due to image loading. How can I optimize this?

Comment: Time to implement some lazy loading ;) It will be similar to downloading contents into your cells etc (http://lazyloadinginuiscrollviewiniphone.blogspot.in/2011/12/lazy-loading-in-uitableview-in-iphone.html).

Comment: I don't think this is my case, since I have no task to download images from network. Images are on filesystem, but loading them each time takes time. If I create dictionary then lazy_add images to it, experience will be same for the first time. Second time user may not even open it. If I add only some images to dictionary on app startup, then it will be waste of memory to keep it there always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sees ok, but maybe the image size is really bigger than the image view bounds.
If it is reduce the the size of the images in the bundle, or if you are taking them somewhere else, try to pre cache them in a directory using the correct size.
ScrollView performace depends on a lot of factors, do you have a lot of transparency in your view? these affect scrolling performance really bad.

Comment: Unfortunately those images are exact size for retina display. I use scale fit attribute for non-retina, so framework will downscale images. I don't have transparency, just cells with imageview. Images are in the filesystem.

Comment: May I ask you the size in point of the image view and the size in pixel of the images also with dpi and format? If the image view is 200pt * 200pt the image should be 400px * 400px 72dpi PNG. PNG are better because they require less time during decompression.

Comment: Another thing... iPAD 2 has NOT a retina display, you should provide a 1:1 ratio between image view points and image pixel, even if you use scale fit attribute, the images will occupy more memory than its required and will take more time to decompress instead of correct ones.

Comment: yeah, the size of UIImageView in points 224x300pt. The size of jpg image on disk is 448x600px @72dpi jpg. I made it jpg in order to keep the size small. There are about 200 images which I distribute with application and having png will make size of my app terribly big.

Comment: I understand iPad 2 is not retina, but this is coming from the fact that I don't want to keep 2 images (retina, non-retina) in order to keep the app size small.

Comment: I understand, but there is always a tradeoff, ipad2 isn't made to handle retina images or big images in general. A way around can be at the first launch resize and save the images in a directory and pick them here. Try to give a shot with correct images if yuo see the performance improvement you want

Comment: Resizing during first launch is good idea if it won't take long. I am also thinking of some memory caching, but hard to determine good algorithm which will not eat up all memory and will provide good user experience.

Comment: You can use NSCache, but with 200 images memory will end up pretty soon

Comment: perhaps I have to define some algorithm which will add/remove images from cache to keep reasonable memory usage. But first going to resize to see performance change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need a cache for the images. You can use SDWebImage for this. 
[SDWebImage Class](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). SDWebImage is an 
asynchronous image downloader with cache support as a UIImageView category.

As you can see in the doc it provides:

- An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the
  Cocoa Touch framework
- An asynchronous image downloader
- An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling
- Animated GIF support
- WebP format support
- A background image decompression
- A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times
- A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
- A guarantee that main thread will never be blocked
- Performances!
- Use GCD and ARC
- Arm64 support